# ajax call on special character

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need an ajax call upon writing # or @ in text box. I have taken this idea from facebook or twitter, when someone inserts @ in comment area a div opens displaying the names of your friends (or anything related) Please help me how can i achieve this.

Comment: i have tried to find the solutions on the internet, but i didn't see any relevant help on this case. This is why i came here for the help.

Comment: If you have seen site more careful then witgout typing # or @ it will popup friends list when typed alphabet found in friend database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want something happenning when user presses the # or @ key you will need to set an `onkeypress` (or `onkeydown`, `onkeyup`) event for that input control.

Within the event handling function (that you set) you will be notified through a parametre (of that function) (or in IE browser through `event` property of `window` object) what key did the user press. By simple `if` test you will know whether that was the # key and if so, you will make your assynchronous ajax call.

As your question wasn't very specific, i hope this gives you some idea about how it's done, and i am sure that if you refine your problem, we will give you more detailed information :)

Comment: Thank you so much Marina, its being a very helpful support. Thank you once again.